# Using Asp.Net Identity DataBase first approach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, identity

I need to integrate Asp.Net latest MVC version with an *existing* database which has an additional column `String Address` to table `dbo.AspNetUsers`

I need to create an instance `ApplicationUser` which has property Address.

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: interesting http://www.itorian.com/2013/11/customize-users-profile-in-aspnet.html

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19940014/asp-net-identity-with-ef-database-first-mvc5

Answer (score 59, accepted):

A possible solution which works for me, basically I am able to integrate Asp.Net Identity User Profiles with an existing Database.

Getting the Asp.Identity Tables:

- Create an MVC Project with Authentication Individual User Account
- Open the DB listed under the DefaultConnection in Web.config. It will be called (aspnet-[timestamp] or something like that.)
- Script the database tables using SQL Server Management Studio (attach database for mdc).

Alternatively use something like http://identity.codeplex.com/

Integrating with your existing db:

- Insert the scripted tables into existing database in SQL Server Management Studio.
- Customize and add relationships to ApplicationUser (if necessary).
- Create new Web Project > MVC > DB First Project > Import DB with EF ... .
- In IdentityModels.cs change the ApplicationDbContext :base("DefaltConnection") to use your project's DbContext.

Now you have the Asp.Identity Tables in your db with ER model in your application.

Asp.Identity Profile Adding new properties:

- Enable Entity Framework Code First Database Migrations, just in VS go under Tools ‘Package Manager Console’,
- Execute the command “Enable-Migrations”; Once we enabled the database migrations, we can go ahead and add new properties for our UserProfile
- To Add new properties modify IdentityModels.cs file, example:

---

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public string EmailID { get; set; }
}
```

---

Add New Migration

- Once we added the properties, bring the Package Manager Console and execute the following command.

  Add-Migration “YouMigrationName”

This command will generate a database script file, now execute following command to run this script file against the database.

```
Update-Database
```

Now, all the new properties will turn into table fields in the same database table.

I hope it can help others, if you have a better idea please let me know.

Comment: Actually this doesn't work for me. I have enabled migrations, added new properties, added new migration but when I try to "Update-Database" it says "There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database.". So it seems, it doesn't update database, instead try to re-create it.

Comment: May I know why all asp.net mvc use localdb as default authentication database?

Comment: Why use migrations if it's database-first approach? My understanding is that migrations are used in code-first approach to apply code changes to the database

Comment: Where does one actually locate "(aspnet-[timestamp] or something like that.)"? Does that live in the project folder?

Comment: How come every database-first discussion I find regarding the entity tables involves code first?

Comment: This works but It doen't match the requirements in the title "DataBase first approach"

Comment: This is a solution for adding Asp.Net Identity tables to an existing database, without having to recreate the database. Other than that, it is still a code-first solution.

Answer (score 20):

Take a look at these projects on GitHub:

- https://github.com/kriasoft/AspNet.Identity - Identity Database Project + [VS Template](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6780f8e4-d204-4e88-83c2-853098727ffb)
- https://github.com/kriasoft/AspNet-Server-Template - Sample / reference project

Which includes:

- SQL Database Project Template for ASP.NET Identity 2.0
- Entity Framework Database-First Provider(s)
- Source Code and Samples

[image]

Comment: Any one got any other resources as how to use https://github.com/kriasoft/AspNet.Identity as its documentation doesn't say much, What if I am not starting from scratch. I simply want to link my identity context to my db first context/.

Comment: @Zapnologica, well.. it's more suited for database-first approach, where you generate EF DbContext / Model based on the actual db schema.

Comment: So can it not be used with db first? Only way i can think is to re implement all the stores and use my own `dbContext` pointing to my db first model?

Comment: @Zapnologica [ASP.NET Server Template](https://github.com/kriasoft/AspNet-Server-Template) project contains a complete sample of an ASP.NET Identity solution and EF DbFirst development appraoch.

Answer (score 2):

I had recently the same problem. I had an apllication created with DBFirst aproach and I needed to add Identity. This is what I did.

0. Install the next packages:

> ```
>    1. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
>    2. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
>    3. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
>    4. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
>    5. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore
>    6. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Aututhentication.JwtBearer
> ```

1. Do DbContext inherit from IdentityDbContext, like this:

```
public partial class BookStoresDBContext : IdentityDbContext
```

2. OnModelCreating  I called the base constructor in order to avoid an error like "'IdentityUserLogin' requires a primary key to be defined"

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
 }
```

3. As far as it was a created project the StringConnection was already there, if not add it.
4. On the Startup.cs configure Identity service on ConfigureServices

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<BookStoresDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("BookStoreDB")));

    services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
    {
        options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 5;
    
    }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<BookStoresDBContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

}
```

5. You can configure the Authetication service too

   ```
   services.AddAuthentication(auth =>
   {
       auth.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
       auth.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
   }).AddJwtBearer(options => {
       options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
       {
           ValidateIssuer = true,
           ValidateAudience = true,
           RequireExpirationTime = true,
           IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Your key to encrypt"))
       };
   });
   ```
6. Then run the migration from the Package Manager Console

```
Add-Migration InitDb
```

7. On the migration file, remove all the migrationBuilder.CreateTable for the tables you already have in your Database
8. Update the Database from the Package Manager Console

```
Update-Database
```

9. Then you will see the Identity Tables on your db

[image]

I hope it result usefull

Comment: Advice for those like me who need **remedial** help: Do NOT `Scaffold-DbContext` / `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold`  against your existing 'AspNetxxx' tables. That model you would be generating already comes with Identity. Try this exercise: Build a code-first .NET 6 MVC app from the template with individual accounts. Do initial migration to create the DB. Run, register, log in/out. Then delete the migration folder in the solution and the migrations table in DB. The app still works fine. (Is it still code-first?) Look at `ApplicationDBContext.cs`. Now begin to think about your customizations.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add migrations and update the database. Otherwise it throws a dependecy injection exceptions for the identity.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

public class MyUser : IdentityUser 
    { 
        public virtual MyUserInfo MyUserInfo { get; set; } 
    }

```
public class MyUserInfo{ 
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string FirstName { get; set; } 
    public string LastName { get; set; } 
} 
public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<MyUserInfo> //Edited to MyUserInfo
{ 
    public MyDbContext() 
        : base("DefaultConnection") 
    { 
    } 
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MyUserInfo> MyUserInfo { get; set; } 
 }
```

Getting Profile information

When the User Logs in, you can display the profile information by doing the following 
Get the current logged in `UserId`, so you can look the user up in ASP.NET Identity system

```
var currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

Instantiate the `UserManager` in ASP.Identity system so you can look up the user in the system

```
var manager = new UserManager<MyUser>(new UserStore<MyUser>(new MyDbContext()));
```

Get the User object

```
var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

Get the profile information about the user

```
currentUser.MyUserInfo.FirstName
```