# Web api Odata error when scaffolding

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

I've tried to scaffold Odata controller for this entity:

```
        #region Attributes

        public Guid TreningId { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTimeWhenTreningCreated { get; set; }

        #endregion

        #region Navigational properties

        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }

        public int RoutineId { get; set; }
        public Routine Routine { get; set; }


        #endregion
```

And scaffolding went fine, I'm also using ASP.net Identity, but my user class and database context are defined in another project like this:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
    {
        public String Something { get; set; }

    }

And database context looks like this:

     public class DatabaseContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
        {
            public MadBarzDatabaseContext()
                : base("DefaultConnection")
            {
                Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
            }
           ...

 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>()
                .ToTable("Users");
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .ToTable("Users");
}
    }
```

Note: I don't have anywhere line:

```
public DbSet<User> Users{ get; set; }
```

So after scaffolding my Web api project added this line to my class DatabaseContext:

```
public DbSet<User> IdentityUsers { get; set; }
```

But then when I tried to fetch anything from database I got error:

```
    Multiple object sets per type are not supported. The object sets 'IdentityUsers' and 'Users' can both contain instances of type 'Domain.Model.UserAggregate.User'.
```

If I delete that line I get error:

```
An exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

At line (in my WebApiConfig)

```
config.Routes.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());
```

If remove lines (from my WebApiConfig):

```
builder.EntitySet<Trening>("Trening");
builder.EntitySet<User>("IdentityUsers");
```

Everything forks fine again. So probably problem is whit my User entity, so how can I solve this ? (when I scaffold anything that has nothing to do with User, everything is fine)

**EDIT**

I've also deleted these lines from my trening controller:

```
// GET odata/Trening(5)/User
        [Queryable]
        public SingleResult<User> GetUser([FromODataUri] Guid key)
        {
            return SingleResult.Create(db.Trenings.Where(m => m.TreningId == key).Select(m => m.User));
        }
```

And added these lines to WebApiConfig:

```
trenings.EntityType.Ignore(t => t.User);
trenings.EntityType.Ignore(t => t.UserId);
```

But it didn't help.

**EDIT 2**

So I've decided to make new test project and I've followed these tutorials (all of them are basically same):

[Tutorial 1](http://www.itorian.com/2013/11/customize-users-profile-in-aspnet.html)
[Tutorial 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20668328/using-asp-net-identity-database-first-approch)
[Tutorial 3](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/674760/Code-First-Migration-and-Extending-Identity-Accoun)
[Tutorial 4](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/10/customizing-aspnet-identity-in-mvc-5.html)

So I've extended Identity User using Application user class and added test model like this:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Test { get; set; }


    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

And here is whole IdentityModels class:

```
namespace WebApplication2.Models
{

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }

    public ICollection<TestModel> TestModels { get; set; }

}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }



    public DbSet<TestModel> TestModels { get; set; }
}
}
```

And the error remains the same,

I've tried to replace ApplicationUser with  IdentityUser in test model and I've added this line:

public DbSet ApplicationUsers { get; set; }

But still same error.

Note: this time I scaffolded Odata controller with TestModel.

Answer (score 0):

Havent seen this error before. According to your errormessage, it looks like these lines are causing your troubles:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>()
            .ToTable("Users");
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .ToTable("Users");
```