# Renaming dbo.AspNetUsers table

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to rename the default table names generated by ASP.net Identity 2.0. I read all the articles, the questions and the answers on stackoverflow but im still getting the same error.

I renamed the tables to Roles, UserClaims, Logins, UserRoles and Users. I also changed the application dbcontext to the following

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);


        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("Users", "dbo");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles", "dbo");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles", "dbo");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims", "dbo");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins", "dbo");

    }

}
```

But i keep getting the `Invalid object name 'dbo.AspNetUsers'.` error, and I have no idea why its still trying to locate *AspNetUsers* in the first place instead of just *Users* although i made the changes above. Totally desperate by now.

[image]

The database as well, same columns with the new table names:

[image]

And the SQL database project:

[image]

Comment: @tmg yup, attached another screenshot to the question to show the structure

Comment: @tmg i removed all the tables from the database, and built the SQL Server Project (added another screenshot), do i need to do anything else, e.g. EF migrations on top of that?

Comment: @tmg okay so i did the Enable-Migrations and Update-Database, and it works fine now. through im having a weird AspNet Users table with one column http://1drv.ms/14U52nR. But I'm planning to do a database first approach for the project, how do i use the database first approach to accomplish the same thing, thanks man.

Comment: @tmg okay fair enough, looks like EF7 is abandoning the edmx format, so ill go with the code first approach, can u move your comments in an answer so i can accept them thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update database. `Enable-Migrations` and `Update-Database`, explained in details [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application). The point of EF code first approach is to write our model classes and configurations and each time we change something we use EF migrations to update the database schema.

Database first approach with asp.net-identity-entityframework are explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20668328/using-asp-net-identity-database-first-approch) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19940014/asp-net-identity-with-ef-database-first-mvc5), not so straightforward

Comment: @coderwill check the links for Database first approach. If they do not help you, please make new post

Answer (score 2):

Write the following code in IdentityModels.cs

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DBConnectionString", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Users");
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Write the following code in Application_Start() Method in Global.asax.cs file

```
Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(null);
```