# Getting current user's name in Identity 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

On my `_Layout.cshtml` page of my site, I just want to display the current user's first and last name. This is stored in the `AspNetUsers` database table in the `Name` column.

Anyone know how I can get this data?

I looked in the `UserManager` class, and I see methods like `GetEmail` and `GetPhone`, but nothing to get Name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HttpContext.User](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to get this information like

```
User.Identity.Name
```

(Or) fully qualified name

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.
```

Per your comment, you are trying to get the `UserName` field from `AspNetUsers` table.

Take a look at the below posts

[Cutting Edge Store User Data in ASP.NET Identity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn818488.aspx)

[Using Asp.Net Identity DataBase first approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20668328/using-asp-net-identity-database-first-approach)

Comment: unfortunately that only gives me the `UserName` field. I need the data that is stored in the `Name` field in the `AspNetUsers` table

Answer (score 1):

Can you elaborate more where did Name column came from?

Preferred way of adding columns to AspNetUsers table is by enabling migrations in your project, adding a new property to ApplicationUser class and then adding new migrations and applying it.

By doing it that way you will have access to the new Name property when you fetch User from UserManager.

Answer (score 0):

Just read your question again and there is no column called `Name` in the `AspNetUsers` table, there is a `UserName` column. First name and last name are not held in the `AspNetUsers` table, unless you've added them in, in that case I would create a Stored Proc to return the data from that table.

For accessing *UserName* and *UserId*,

Add the following *using* statement.

> using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;

You can now get more methods from the `HttpContext.User.Identity`.

```
var UserName = User.Identity.GetUserName();
var UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

Thanks