# How to implement Asp.net identity with existing database using database first approach in asp.net mvc core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have to implement asp.net identity in my asp.net core project.I have go through maximum related topics by googling my requirement.but there is not most suitable solution I could find.
If I create project using individual authentication,then i have to apply database migration to my existing database in sql server,tables are then created,but context class is now application user is also added to my project.
and then using database first approach when I create classes of my database using reverse engineering  then another mydatabasenamecontext class is added to project.and then all is do mess with these context classes and their configuration.
 I want that after applying migration,when I use database first approach all existing context class reference must be updated,only one flow of application to db and vice versa can be implement using ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from your question exactly what you're trying to achieve but you can customize ASP.NET Identity to match your pre-existing DB auth schema. Here is a course from Microsoft Virtual Academy that can help:

https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/customizing-aspnet-authentication-with-identity-8647?l=1Yef8hF1_7604984382

Comment: I just want to authenticate my user ,problem is is that by using db first approach when I generate class of my db,class are generated but there is no extension methods like first(),firstordefault() are there,like we have in previous version of mvc,so i decide to use asp.net identity in my project ,when i use asp.net identity and db first approach in my project then two context class are created one with application user context that is created by asp.net identity when I apply migration and second one mydbcontext that is created when i use db first approach?hope You get my problem?

Comment: Does this work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20668328/using-asp-net-identity-database-first-approach