# .NET Core 3.1, EF Core 3.1 DB First approach, Identity

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, ef-database-first

What is the latest recommendation for introducing Identity into your existing .NET Core 3.1 WebApi project using EF Core 3.1 DB First approach ?
So after you scaffold database to create your objects in .net project, how do properly "insert" Identity tables ?
The best solution I could find on this topic is an old SO post from almost 5y ago, so I'm wandering is there a new solution to this ?

[Using Asp.Net Identity DataBase first approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20668328/using-asp-net-identity-database-first-approach)

thanks

Comment: If you want to use the identity db existed in your webapi,you can change your connection string in your web api,and add config in your startup.You can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: But, do you want to use Migrations in a DB First project ?