# Use Microsoft Identity With Database First Projects

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I want to use Identity in my app for authorization/authentication but the problem is that my project is not code first.

I wanted to know is it possible to use it with database first projects ?

Any idea how to do it ?

thanks

Comment: yes. it is possible to db first as well

Comment: read this. hope help you
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20668328/using-asp-net-identity-database-first-approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20668328/using-asp-net-identity-database-first-approach)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use these scripts to setup the database tables.

```
USE [YourDBName]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[AspNetRoleClaims]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetRoleClaims](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ClaimType] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ClaimValue] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [RoleId] [nvarchar](450) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetRoleClaims] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
END
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[AspNetRoles]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetRoles](
    [Id] [nvarchar](450) NOT NULL,
    [ConcurrencyStamp] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [NormalizedName] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetRoles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
END
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[AspNetUserClaims]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ClaimType] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ClaimValue] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [UserId] [nvarchar](450) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetUserClaims] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
END
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[AspNetUserLogins]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins](
    [LoginProvider] [nvarchar](450) NOT NULL,
    [ProviderKey] [nvarchar](450) NOT NULL,
    [ProviderDisplayName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [UserId] [nvarchar](450) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetUserLogins] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [LoginProvider] ASC,
    [ProviderKey] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
END
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles](
    [UserId] [nvarchar](450) NOT NULL,
    [RoleId] [nvarchar](450) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetUserRoles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserId] ASC,
    [RoleId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
END
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[AspNetUsers]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers](
    [Id] [nvarchar](450) NOT NULL,
    [AccessFailedCount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ConcurrencyStamp] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [EmailConfirmed] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [LockoutEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [LockoutEnd] [datetimeoffset](7) NULL,
    [NormalizedEmail] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [NormalizedUserName] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [PasswordHash] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PhoneNumber] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PhoneNumberConfirmed] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [SecurityStamp] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [TwoFactorEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
END
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[AspNetUserTokens]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserTokens](
    [UserId] [nvarchar](450) NOT NULL,
    [LoginProvider] [nvarchar](450) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](450) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetUserTokens] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserId] ASC,
    [LoginProvider] ASC,
    [Name] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
END
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_AspNetRoleClaims_AspNetRoles_RoleId]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[AspNetRoleClaims]'))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetRoleClaims]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_AspNetRoleClaims_AspNetRoles_RoleId] FOREIGN KEY([RoleId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetRoles] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_AspNetRoleClaims_AspNetRoles_RoleId]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[AspNetRoleClaims]'))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetRoleClaims] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_AspNetRoleClaims_AspNetRoles_RoleId]
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_AspNetUserClaims_AspNetUsers_UserId]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[AspNetUserClaims]'))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_AspNetUserClaims_AspNetUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_AspNetUserClaims_AspNetUsers_UserId]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[AspNetUserClaims]'))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_AspNetUserClaims_AspNetUsers_UserId]
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_AspNetUserLogins_AspNetUsers_UserId]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[AspNetUserLogins]'))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_AspNetUserLogins_AspNetUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_AspNetUserLogins_AspNetUsers_UserId]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[AspNetUserLogins]'))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_AspNetUserLogins_AspNetUsers_UserId]
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetRoles_RoleId]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]'))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetRoles_RoleId] FOREIGN KEY([RoleId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetRoles] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetRoles_RoleId]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]'))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetRoles_RoleId]
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetUsers_UserId]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]'))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetUsers_UserId]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]'))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetUsers_UserId]
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_AspNetUserTokens_AspNetUsers_UserId]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[AspNetUserTokens]'))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserTokens]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_AspNetUserTokens_AspNetUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_AspNetUserTokens_AspNetUsers_UserId]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[AspNetUserTokens]'))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserTokens] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_AspNetUserTokens_AspNetUsers_UserId]
GO
```

Comment: after using this query to create identity tables , can I user UserManager ,RoleManager and SignInManager ? also should I add identity and configure it in startup like code-first as well ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.