# Extending current User class to handle Identity

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

We are using forms authentication on our ASP.NET website but are wanting to upgrade to the new Identity Provider. Currently we are using the database first approach and are ultimately wanting to just extend our current User table (not aspnet_users) to use the new identity format. We are using StructureMap to inject our context into our business logic classes. For instance our User service currently has this as its constructor:

```
private readonly SiteModelContainer _context;
public UserService(SiteModelContainer context)
{
    this._context = context;
}
```

And in our IoC registry we have this:

```
var ecsbuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
ecsbuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
ecsbuilder.ProviderConnectionString = @"data source=***;initial catalog=***;persist security         info=True;User ID=***;Password=***;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework";
ecsbuilder.Metadata = @"res://*/Data.***.csdl|res://*/Data.***.ssdl|res://*/Data.***.msl";
string connectionString = ecsbuilder.ToString();
For<SiteModelContainer>().Use<SiteModelContainer>().Ctor<string>("connectionString").Is(connectionString);
For<IUserService>().Use<UserService>();
...all the rest of our services
```

We are also using database first with EDMX and entity framework. Previously we just used ASP.NET authentication as it came out the box and had a separate user table to store profile information, but would like to have everything working off one users class instead.

1)Is it possible to extend our userservice to handle everything related to using Identity? So that Identity uses the same context that we inject into our classes? If so, I am unable to find any articles about it?

2) Are we able to extend our User object if it is created in the EDMX file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have migrated 2 fairly large projects from `MembershipProvider` into Asp.Net Identity and both of the times I ended up rewriting most parts of the user-management and everything that touched user. A fairly chunky rewrites.

What you ask for is possible, but hard and very time consuming. You may start from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25593979/809357) - the OP have got his db-first project running with identity. And we had a discussion in comments with some links that might help you.