# Creating AspNet Identity database and its tables from scratch : database first approach

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm starting to build a new web application from scratch where I want to use Microsoft's latest [AspNetIdentity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt173608(v=vs.108).aspx) to manage logins and identities in my system. I have previously used asp.net Membership provider. There, at the beginning of application creation it was simply possible to create all the related tables and views of Asp.Net membership provider through a wizard or by running a simple command `aspnet_regsql.exe` on Visual Studio command prompt as described in [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/sukumarraju/installing-asp-net-membership-services-database-in-sql-server-expreess) blog post.

I'm looking for something very similar wizard to get started with AspNetIdentity as well? I was reading lot of blog posts e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28636511/how-to-create-asp-net-identity-tables-inside-existing-database) which suggests that all the tables of AspNetIdentity will get automatically created through code first migration once you provide connection string to the DbContext.

But, I want to start from scratch or you can say DB first approach where I would like to see what all tables it creates then, add all my own required tables into the same database, build its relationships with aspNetIdentity tables to get started. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it's just not like the membership provider was. Go to nuget and add it to your project then enable-migrations and add your first migration. Look in your migrations file and you'll see what it will create.

Comment: So the database first approach doesn't exist explicitly at all for using AspNetIdentity?

Comment: I've always used database first, generated the database, then populated my identity tables with identity. I don't know if there is a better way.