# Can I mix up Asp.Net Identity framework with my own tables in the connecting databases?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I need to use Asp.Net Identity in my web api project and I am able to use it with the Identity scaffolded tables.

My question is that can I use it with my own tables while bypassing the Identity tables.
Any insight on this would be helpful.

Comment: maybe this help you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/28637166/6350942

Comment: What do you mean "while bypassing the Identity tables"? Identity framework generates AspNetRoles, AspNetUserClaims, AspNetUserLogins, and AspNetUserRoles tables. What will your own table schema look like? Are your tables using completely different schema compared to Identity? Or you just want to rename the tables and maybe customize the schema (i.e., add additional columns, rename some columns, remove some columns)?

Comment: @Ali7091 Thanks, but that's not what I need to do.

Comment: @kimbaudi I do not want to use tables generated by Identity. Instead I am asking if my own custom schemas could be used with Identity.?

Comment: Given that I don't know what your table schemas are like, I don't know if its possible to use your own tables. If your tables are similar to Identity scaffolded table, it is better to just customize Identity framework to generate tables to match your own table. For instance, you can configure Identity Framework to change schema, table names, column names, and column data types. But you can't just create your own tables and configure Identity framework to use your tables without completely modifying the underlying logic used in Identity Framework.

Comment: @kimbaudi Thanks for the response.