# Integrating ASP.NET Core Identity db with an already created database in a Razor Pages app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have been following [this](https://zoboko.com/read/aspnet-core-in-action-3d5l410j?hash=cb109d6fed876fa47bb992993b661e58) book on how to Add Identity to an existing project (specifically section 14.4). I have done the following

- Added the ASP.NET Core Identity NuGet packages
- Configured Startup to use Authentication Middleware and added Identity services to the DI container
- Updated the EF Core data model with the Identity entities

> Code for updating the EF Core data model to support Identity

```
namespace Hoook.Data

    {
        public class HoookDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
        {
            public HoookDbContext(DbContextOptions<HoookDbContext> options) : base(options)
            {
    
            }
            public DbSet<Venture> Ventures { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

> Code for custom user type which inherits from IdentityUser

```
namespace Hoook.Data

{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {

    }
}
```

> Startup.cs code for adding Identity service to DI

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options =>
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true).AddEntityFrameworkStores<HoookDbContext>();
```

Now I have then ran the following command in VSCode
`dotnet ef migrations add AddIdentitySchema`

Then I ran `dotnet ef database update`

At this point I am to assume my database is updated and contains the Identity tables, but that is incorrect. How Am I to add the Identity tables to my existing database? I have searched through these [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651342/how-to-add-asp-net-mvc5-identity-authentication-to-existing-database/25651908#25651908), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20668328/using-asp-net-identity-database-first-approach), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28636511/how-to-create-asp-net-identity-tables-inside-existing-database?noredirect=1&lq=1) stackoverflow questions with no luck.

Adding a screenshot of my SSMS Migration History and tables. The migration took but no Identity tables have been populated.


[image]

**UPDATE**

It may help to note, I have created an Identity app using the .NET Core CLI with `new webapp -au Indi-  vidual -uld`. Inside the migrations of that app after running `dotnet ef database update`, the Migrations up and down methods are actually populated. However in my app when adding the migration following the above steps, my Migration file looks as so:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

#nullable disable

namespace Hoook.Migrations
{
    public partial class AddIdentitySchema : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {

        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do commands "migrations add" and "database update" return any errors?

Comment: No errors. running `dotnet ef migrations list` however I get the error that more than one DbContext was found. Which was not the case previously. however if I run `dotnet ef migrations list --context HoookdbContext` then the migrations are listed. I don't know if that information helps the cause

Comment: You can ignore the above about the error on the `dotnet ef migrations list` issue. It seems when I was trying to figure this post's issue out I ran a `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold` command and it generated another context file which I have now deleted.

Comment: Try command `dotnet ef migrations add AddIdentitySchema --context HoookdbContext` as it's said in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#common-options

Comment: If I look at my Microsoft SQL Server Management studio under my Migrations history, the migration to `AddIdentitySchema` is there. Just the tables are not populated. I can add a screenshot of the tables and migration list above as well if that will help?

Comment: Your migration file is empty, it should not be empty. In your `HoookDbContext ` there should be a method called `OnModelCreating` make sure you are calling the base method in it : `    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
//.... REST OF YOUR LOGIC
    } `

Comment: Once that is sorted, then try add the migration again - this time the migration file should not be empty.

Comment: From the migration file you shared, it seems that you did not migrate successfully.

Comment: @DawoodAwan so I would have to use Fluent API to configure my model. Calling `builder.Entity<TEntity>.ToTable("Some name")` for each [entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0) type in Identity. Then also create the corresponding class to that entity?

Comment: Not exactly, all Identity related Entities are already included in the `IdentityDbContext` class. You can see the source code here: `https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/main/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/IdentityDbContext.cs`

But if you are not calling the `base.OnModelCreating()` in your own `OnModelCreating` EF will not be able to find the ones from IdentityDbContext.
How are you currently configuring your entities? Do you have OnModelCreating in `HoookDbContext  `?

Comment: I see. So I just need to override `OnModelCreating` and call `base.OnModelCreating()` to have the entities added from the `IdentityDbContext` to the model. However, I also have the ability to change the default table names  and generic types from Identity. But the most important step is calling `base.OnModelCreating()` to be able to have the entities added to my database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comments below and @DawoodAwan, I have figured out the missing piece. I did not override the `OnModelCreating` method and subsequently call the `base.OnModelCreating()` method inside of it. The solution is in the below code. I have also gone ahead and updated the names of the default tables in this example:

```
using Hoook.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Hoook.Data
{
    public class HoookDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public HoookDbContext(DbContextOptions<HoookDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Users");
            builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles");
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>().ToTable("Claims");
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>().ToTable("Tokens");
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>().ToTable("Logins");
            builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>().ToTable("RoleClaims");
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().ToTable("UserRoles");
        }
        public DbSet<Venture> Ventures { get; set; }
    }
}
```