# How to set existing DB with ASP.NET identity?

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I want to set my existing database `TestDB` into my application so that Identity will create their tables inside this database.

But I am getting error:

> Cannot attach the file 'D:\TestApp\TestApp\App_Data\TestDB.mdf' as database 'TestDB'.

I have done couple of things which are

1. I removed `defaultconnection` to `TestDBConnection` in `web.config`

   ```
   <add name="TestDBConnection"
   connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\TestDB.mdf;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=True"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   ```
2. I changed in `IdentityModels.cs`

   ```
   public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
   {
      public ApplicationDbContext()
           : base("TestDBConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
      { }
   ```
3. In package Manager Console,

   ```
   PM>enable-migrations
   ```
4. In `Configuration.cs`,

   ```
   internal sealed class Configuration : 
   DbMigrationsConfiguration<TestApp.Models.ApplicationDbContext>
   {
       public Configuration()
       {
           AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
       }
   ```

Please guide me where am I going wrong. I am looking for your suggestions.

Comment: It would appear your problem has nothing to do with [making ASP.NET Identity use an existing database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25651342/11683). Verify that you can [attach that database file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17012839/11683) in principle.

Comment: @GSerg, I just changed connection string to `<add name="TestDBConnection" connectionString="Data Source=LAPTOP-E06VT3CD\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />` and it worked for me now. Thank you