# How to change primary key for Users in Asp.Net Identity with MySQL as storage provider

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-identity, owin

I went through this article http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/implementing-a-custom-mysql-aspnet-identity-storage-provider and was able to make Identity 2.2.1 work with MySQL as database.

However, now I would like to convert the Primary Key from GUID to INT. I tried to follow the link below but am getting errors

Link Followed: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity

Error related to: 
IdentityUserRole
IdentityUserClaim
IdentityUserLogin

As these are defined with ASpnet.Identity.EntityFramework and not in AspNet.Identity.MySQL

Can someone please help me solve the issue

Comment: You have to change the type in a few places. Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27847167/219406). If you cannot find your solution there I'll try and help.

Comment: Thanks a lot @LeftyX for replying. I tried to follow the link you referenced however, it seems a little complicated to me. It would be great if u could guide me. This is exactly where am I stuck right now - https://forums.asp.net/p/2062668/5950477.aspx?Re+How+to+change+primary+key+for+Identity+with+MySQL+as+storage+provider

There is no extension for MySQLDatabase