# ASP Identity custom database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have a MVC5 project and I've been following this tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity

Basically I want to use my own database than using the code-first default approach. I've got all my custom Store and Identity covered, but I have no idea how to change my application to use my custom Context because the default code from MVC5 project use code-first behaviour.

I'm also confused about the code in IdentityModels.cs and CreatePerOwinContext in Startup does. Can someone explain this to me or give me a link to 101 tutorial? I've tried looking around the Internet and SO but I still can't find a proper documentation/step by step tutorial.

My custom UserStore:

```
public class UserStore : IUserStore<IdentityUser, int>
{
    public UserStore() { ... }
    public UserStore(MySQLDatabase database) { ... }
    public Task CreateAsync(IdentityUser user) { ... }
    public Task DeleteAsync(IdentityUser user) { ... }
    public Task<IdentityUser> FindByIdAsync(int userId) { ... }
    public Task<IdentityUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName) { ... }
    public Task UpdateAsync(IdentityUser user) { ... }
    public void Dispose() { ... }
}
```

My custom IdentityUser:

```
public class IdentityUser : IUser<int>
{
    public IdentityUser() { ... }
    public IdentityUser(string userName) { ... }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

IdentityModels.cs default code:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

StartUp:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                { 
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                }
            });            
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
            app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you read about [Migration of an Existing Website from SQL Membership to ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity) and [Implemention of a Custom MySQL ASP.NET Identity Storage Provider](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/implementing-a-custom-mysql-aspnet-identity-storage-provider)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Identity with EF Database First MVC5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19940014/asp-net-identity-with-ef-database-first-mvc5)