# Entity Framework does not create identity tables on existing database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

My current project has two database connections:

The first is used for the IdentityModel and uses a local .mdf file. The second i created on an external SQL Server and was imported using Database first.

Now i would like to create the IdentityModel tables on the external sql server so only one connection / database is used. I changed the ApplicationDbContext to match the external connectionname in the web.config.

**ApplicationDbContext**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("SAMPLEEntities", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

**Web.config**

```
<add name="SAMPLEEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.modelone.csdl|res://*/Models.modelone.ssdl|res://*/Models.modelone.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=thedatabase;initial catalog=SAMPLE;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Now i would think the tables would be generated, but this is not the case. When i tried to do a manual update in the Package Manager Console, i get the following error:

*Creating a DbModelBuilder or writing the EDMX from a DbContext created using Database First or Model First is not supported. EDMX can only be obtained from a Code First DbContext created without using an existing DbCompiledModel.*

I also tried to import the local .mdf file into the sql server so i could copy the tables, but the mdf file is created by VS 2015 and would not load in SQL Server 2012.

Any suggestions how to generate / add the tables in the external SQL Server?

Comment: can you list the *exact* command you are issuing that is triggering that error message?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to mix Database First with Code First.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19940014/asp-net-identity-with-ef-database-first-mvc5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer,

Step 1. Use the following SQL Script to create the tables on the external sql server:

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[__MigrationHistory]    Script Date: 5/15/2014 3:57:55 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[__MigrationHistory](
    [MigrationId] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [ContextKey] [nvarchar](300) NOT NULL,
    [Model] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL,
    [ProductVersion] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.__MigrationHistory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [MigrationId] ASC,
    [ContextKey] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO


/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[AspNetRoles]    Script Date: 5/15/2014 4:04:57 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetRoles](
    [Id] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetRoles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO



/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[AspNetUsers]    Script Date: 5/15/2014 4:06:02 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers](
    [Id] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [Hometown] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [EmailConfirmed] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [PasswordHash] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [SecurityStamp] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PhoneNumber] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PhoneNumberConfirmed] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [TwoFactorEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [LockoutEndDateUtc] [datetime] NULL,
    [LockoutEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [AccessFailedCount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO



/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims]    Script Date: 5/15/2014 4:05:11 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [ClaimType] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ClaimValue] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUserClaims] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserClaims_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserClaims_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId]
GO



/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins]    Script Date: 5/15/2014 4:05:37 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins](
    [LoginProvider] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [ProviderKey] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUserLogins] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [LoginProvider] ASC,
    [ProviderKey] ASC,
    [UserId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserLogins_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserLogins_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId]
GO



/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]    Script Date: 5/15/2014 4:05:50 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles](
    [UserId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [RoleId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserId] ASC,
    [RoleId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles_dbo.AspNetRoles_RoleId] FOREIGN KEY([RoleId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetRoles] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles_dbo.AspNetRoles_RoleId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId]
GO
```

Step 2: Change the web.config connection of the identity model to match the following (do not re-use or change the edmx connection)

```
<add name="IdentityDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=MYSERVER;Initial Catalog=MYDATABASE;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Step 3: Set the connection in IdentityModel.cs

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("IdentityDbContext", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was struggling with this a lot. Thanks a lot bro.