# Merging DBContext created using EDMX file and Identity DBContext

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am currently using Entity Framework (edmx) in a separate Model Solution. This edmx file will automatically generate DBContext file and I believe this **DBContext** is **non-editable**. Now we are adding a new web application in our project and I am planning to implement **ASPNET Identity** for Authentication and Authorization purpose.

On the basic MVC template, a separate DBContext (IdentityDBContext) is created to handle user and role activities. I have the following questions

1. Can I merge this IdentityDBContext to my existing DBContext (note my edmx DBContext is non-editable)?
2. Is it advisable to call 2 separate DBContext (in our case Identity and DBContext) in the event of any action call?
3. I already have existing tables like ApplicationUser, Roles table, etc. Can I just extend my existing entities by implementing the Identity classes (like in the link : https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/Customizing-the-ASPNET-Identity-Data-Model-with-the-Entity-Framework-Fluent-API--Part-1)

Comment: Why don't you use CodeFirst approach?

Comment: We already have DBStructure and all other architecture like Repository from other Windows project. We are planning to build a web application on top of this business and data layer.

Comment: You should look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19940014/asp-net-identity-with-ef-database-first-mvc5